# Can I access a controller with same name in a different location via ajax?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 MVC controllers named `CommonController.cs` in two different locations. Here are both of the paths relative to the root:

1. `/Controllers/CommonController.cs`
2. `/CDS/Controllers/CommonController.cs`

This is presenting an issue when I try to make an `AJAX` call to the first common controller. The url in the ajax call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
            cache: false,
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ROOT_URL + 'Common/GetCountries',
            data: { },
//more code
```

Is there a way to access this controller and still keep the same named controller in a different location or do I have to rename one of the controllers?

Comment: Your life would be made somewhat easier with a rename. Failing that, try modifying your route settings to assign a different URL to one of the controllers.

Comment: I suggest you put your 2nd controller in an Area.  Then, you can change your route mapping to make it work.

Comment: Either rename it or configure the routing so that the route name is different. By default the url would be `controllerName/actionName/parameters`, I am not sure why you have `Controllers/Common` in the url, maybe it would be better to also provide your routing configuration to get a better answer.

Comment: @Igor sorry that was a testing error that wasn't removed. Updated to match what is currently running

Comment: @Ian currently we are moving forward with the simplest approach which is renaming the controller. I was curious if there was a way to due this with a pure JavaScript solution.

Comment: check my updated answer. any query you can ask to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add manually your controller path in `RouteConfig.cs` class. If you declare both controller then it find easily.

You can make some changes in `RouteConfig.cs` as given below. I hope it may be help to you.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Country",
            url: "/Controllers/Index",
            defaults: new { controller = "CommonController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "State",
            url: "/CDS/Controllers/Details/5",
            defaults: new { controller = "CommonController", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```